# Optimal motherboard for 256GB RAM and dual Nvidia RTX 3090

Tags: graphics-cards, processor, motherboard, memory

I am in the process of building a workstation for photogrammetry and 3D Modeling.

My day to day work, involves going out to field and scanning environments using drone enabled 3D scanners or 360 video cameras.

Then proccesing that data on a computer, doing data cleanup and often replace badly scanned or unwanted objects in scenes using 3D modelled assets.

- No video games.
- No hard drives. (I use cloud storage)

I am stuck on the motherboard part. I need it to have 3x NVMe connectors (latest gen), support 256GB of RAM and have enough PCie and physical space for x2 RTX 3090.

I've been looking these past two days. and every motherboard just falls short of one or the other requirement. Price is not an issue but it must on the martket (not coming out soon) Any help would be appreciated.

| Part | Name |
| --- | --- |
| CPU | 5950x |
| GPU x1 | RTX 3090 |
| GPU x2 | RTX 3090 |
| RAM (256 GB) | Corsair Vengeance RGB RT 256GB (8x32GB) DDR4 3600MHz C18 |
| SSDx1 | SAMSUNG 980 PRO SSD 2TB PCIe NVMe Gen 4 |
| SSDx2 | SAMSUNG 980 PRO SSD 2TB PCIe NVMe Gen 4 |
| SSDx3 | SAMSUNG 980 PRO SSD 2TB PCIe NVMe Gen 4 |
| PSU | Seasonic PRIME TX 1600 |
| Water Coolor | ARCTIC Liquid Freezer II 360 |
| Fans |  |
| Motherboard |  |
| Case |  |

Comment: No motherboard that I know of supports both AM4 and 8 sticks of RAM. I prefer the way @Yuri goes, try Threadripper

Comment: list of mobo with 256gb ram : https://pangoly.com/en/hardware/motherboard/maximum-supported-ram/256-gb

Comment: like was said the AM4 socket... X570... is only going to have 4 dimm slots supporting 32gb dimms.  You would need to go to sTRX4 on the AMD side or go Intel, or scale back to 128gb ram on AM4.

Answer (score 0):

Since price is not issue - better aim for Threadripper, not Ryzen9. More cores, more memory bandwidth, MUCH more PCIE channels.

https://www.amd.com/en/chipsets/str40 motherboards - some with 3-4 pcie4 nvme slots already

[https://www.amazon.com/ASUS-M-2-X16-Expansion-Card/dp/B084HMHGSP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B084HMHGSP) card - if need extra pcie 4.0 nvme slots

Answer (score 0):

BaseBoard Product   WS X299 PRO

will support what you are looking for- i have it with 256gb and 2x 3090ti. It works a charm

Comment: Hi Ted, can you provide some more justification on why you'd recommend picking X299—a relatively old platform—over something newer, like Threadripper TRX50 or Xeon W680?